# Most significant decimal digit (or 0.3 - 0.1 = 0.1 )

Tags: r, floating-point, rounding, floor

This operation should return `2`, but it returns `1` instead because of the floating point representation:

```
a <- .3
b <- .1
floor((a-b)*10)
```

I basically want the first digit after the point, of the actual base-10 result, not the floating-point computer's result. In this case `a` and `b` only have one decimal digit, but in most situations there will be more. Examples:

- `0.3-0.1=0.2` so I want the `2`
- `0.5-0.001=0.499` so I want the `4`
- `0.925-0.113=0.812` so I want the `8`
- `0.57-0.11=0.46` so I want the `4`
- `0.12-0.11=0.01` so I want the `0`

that is, not rounding but truncating. I thought of using this:

```
floor(floor((a-b)*100)/10)
```

but I'm not sure if that is the best I can do.

**update:** indeed, it doesn't work (see comments below):

```
floor(floor((.9-.8)*100)/10) # gives 0 instead of 1
floor(round((.5-.001)*100)/10) # gives 5 instead of 1
```

**update 2:** think this does work (at least in all cases listed so far):

```
substring(as.character(a-b),first=3,last=3)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: When do you want the value to be rounded up, and when do you want it to not be?  You need to better define the desired behavior.  For example, what should be returned by `.5 - .001` and how do you differentiate this from `.3 - .1`?

Comment: It's not rounding, just truncating. See examples in edited question

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's just truncating, but due to the way that `.3 - .1` is stored, you need to round up to get `.2`.  Oh, and try your latest attempt on `1-.9` or `.9-.8`.  This is more complicated than it appears.

Comment: `floor(round((a-b)*100)/10)` attempt breaks on `.5-.001`.  That's why I ask, when to you want the value to be rounded up, and when do you want to not be?

Comment: You're right. I added a new alternative that first converts it to string so (I think) we get rid of the floating-point issue, and then take the 3rd character (1st after the point)

Comment: Again, I need the actual base-10 result, not the computer's floating-point representation. So, when should we round up or down? I don't know! depends on what the computer does. I always want to truncate the base-10 result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because the information is no longer there:
doubles cannot exactly represent decimal numbers.

If you are fine with an approximate solution,
you can add a small number, and truncate the result.
For instance, if you know that your numbers have at most 14 digits,
the following would work:

```
first_digit <- function(x, epsilon=5e-15)
  floor( (x+epsilon) * 10 )
first_digit( .3   - .1   ) # 2
first_digit( .5   - .001 ) # 4
first_digit( .925 - .113 ) # 8
first_digit( .57  - .11  ) # 4
first_digit( .12  - .11  ) # 0
```

If you wanted the first *significant* digit (that means "first non-zero digit"), 
you could use:

```
first_significant_digit <- function(x, epsilon=5e-14)
  floor( (x+epsilon) * 10^-floor(log10(x+epsilon)) )
first_significant_digit(0.12-0.11) # 1
```

Comment: Yep, this should work. All numbers come from a file where there are at most 4 decimal digits. Do you think `substring(as.character(a-b),first=3,last=3)` would work too?

Comment: If they have at most 4 decimal places then you could load them, multiply by 1e4, round them, then convert to integers. Then you won't have to deal with floating point errors.